# System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column Au_ID on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'

Tags: c#, user-interface

System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column Au_ID on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'

This error shows whenever I try to add a data in the datasource. It successfully adds the data though, it just wont update the display properly (I think?)

An error also occurs when I delete a data. A catch error saying 'No value given for one more required parameters' shows up. It also successfully deletes the selected record though.

The error occurs at this line/method for the adding data part

```
private void BooksOledbBind()
{
    //binding controls
    txtAuthorID.DataBindings.Add("Text", booksTable, "Au_ID"); //errors here
    txtAuthorName.DataBindings.Add("Text", booksTable, "Author");
    txtYearBorn.DataBindings.Add("Text", booksTable, "Year_Born");
}
```

here are some code snippets of what I think may be related to the problem

```
//code for adding new data
private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stateValue = "View";
    GetState(stateValue);

    ClearBind();

    isAdding = true;

    if (txtAuthorID.Text == "" || txtAuthorName.Text == "" || txtYearBorn.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fields cannot be empty", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        query = "INSERT INTO Authors (Au_ID, Author, Year_Born) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Au_ID", Convert.ToInt32(txtAuthorID.Text));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Author", txtAuthorName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Year_Born", Convert.ToInt32(txtYearBorn.Text));

            try
            {
                // Execute the query
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record added successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }

        BooksOledb();
        BooksOledbBind();
    }
    
}
```

```
//code for deleting data
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAuthorID.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select a record to delete.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return;
    }

    stateValue = "View";
    GetState(stateValue);

    // Prompt the user for confirmation
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        query = "DELETE FROM Authors WHERE Au_ID = ?";

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
        {
            // Explicitly cast the Au_ID value to an integer
            int authorID;
            if (int.TryParse(txtAuthorID.Text, out authorID))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Au_ID", authorID);

                try
                {
                    // Execute the DELETE query
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                    // Clear bindings for other controls, reload data, and rebind controls
                    ClearBind();
                    BooksOledb();
                    BooksOledbBind();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Author ID.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
private void BooksOledb()
{
    booksCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    booksAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    booksAdapter.SelectCommand = booksCommand;
    booksTable = new DataTable();

    if (isAdding == false)
    {
        
        booksAdapter.Fill(booksTable);
    }
    

    //establish currency manager
    booksManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[booksTable];
}
```

I have checked multiple times that I put the correct column name. I really don't have any idea on what to do now [image: database columns][image: gui layout][image: delete error message]

video sample of errors
https://insights.gg/v/48S5M6JQOGkvQdWQzD1zkx